# New user, Pi keeps asking for password

Tags: pi-3, user

I made a new user on my Raspberry Pi for myself and it keeps asking for my password when I do things like `sudo apt-get install`. How do I make it an administrator?

Comment: Explained on Raspberry’s web site

Answer (score 5):

You can manually add the user to `sudoers`, but this is only part of the story.

If you want the user to have the same privileges you should set the groups.
The `pi` user is normally a member of `pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi`

This can be done with the following command (replace username with the actual name).

```
for GROUP in $(groups pi | sed 's/.*:\spi//'); do sudo adduser username $GROUP; done
```

(the `sed` command is there to remove group `pi` so the new user does not share files with `pi`)

NOTE editing the sudoers file is **NOT** recommended - many have broken their systems by getting this wrong.

Answer (score 3):

On Raspbian you have two common options:

**Option 1:** Add the already created user (i.e. with the name "john") to the group "sudo":

`pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo usermod -aG sudo john`

**Option 2:** Edit the sudoers file:

`pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo visudo`

By default you'll find this line (do not remove/overwrite it): `root  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`. Just add `john  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL'` or, if you want passwordless root access, add `john  ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL`.

`visudo` provides basic sanity checks, parses the sudoers file after your edit and will not save your changes if there is a syntax error. I'd not recommended to use other tools like nano for this job.

Reboot is not required, but for security reasons only a sudoer user can make these changes.

Comment: Of course to run this command requires you to login as the Pi user (or another user with root privileges).